# How to continuously update a part of the page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

http://pastebin.com/dttyN3L6

The file that processes the form is called upload.php

I have never really used jquery/js so I am unsure how I would do this or where I would put the code.

It has something to do with this `setInterval (loadLog, 2500);`

Also, how can I make it so the user can submit a form without the page refreshing?

```
 $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "upload.php",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  

  }  
});  
return false;  `
```

and

```
 <?php 
 $conn1 = mysqli_connect('xxx') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
 $sql = "SELECT * from text ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql) or die('Error querying database.');
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo  '<p>' . $row['words'] . '</p>';
 }
 mysqli_close($conn1);

 ?>

 </div>

 <?php     
 if (!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {

 } else {
      require_once('form.php'); 
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Whats with that pastebin indenting? Can you post your code here?

Comment: Research the [PeriodicalUpdater](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/periodicalupdater) plugin for jQuery.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can submit a form without refreshing a page something like this:

**form.php:**

```
<form action='profile.php' method='post' class='ajaxform'>
 <input type='text' name='txt' value='Test Text'>
 <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

<div id='result'>Result comes here..</div>
```

**profile.php:**

```
<?php
      // All form data is in $_POST

      // Now perform actions on form data here and 
      // create an result array something like this
      $arr = array( 'result' => 'This is my result' );
      echo json_encode( $arr );
?>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.ajaxform').submit( function() {

        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                        // loop to set the result(value)
                        // in required div(key)
                        for(var id in data) {
                            jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
                        }
                      }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

**And If you want to call an ajax request without refreshing page after a particular time, you can try something like this:**

```
var timer, delay = 300000;

timer = setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type    : 'POST',
      url     : 'profile.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data    : $('.ajaxform').serialize(),
      success : function(data){
                  for(var id in data) {
                    jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
                  }
                }
    });
}, delay);
```

And you can stop the timer at any time like this:

```
clearInterval( timer );
```

Hope this will give you a direction to complete your task.

Comment: Instead of using for(index in array), you should use jQuery's $.each() method. I tend to believe that if you include a library, you should make full use of it and not mix and match.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple.
To access elements using Jquery you use css selectors, for example, to get value of an input field with name "foo" you do the following:

```
var fooVal = $("input[name=foo]").val();
```

To send it over to the server you are to append an event listener (for example, click) to the submit button/any other element

```
var data = { varName : fooVal };
var url = "http://example.com";
var responseDataType = "json";
function parseResponse(JSON)
{
   // your code handling server response here, it's called asynchronously, so you might want to add some indicator for the user, that your request is being processed
}

$("input[type=submit]").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val("query processing");
    $.post(url,data, parseResponse, responseDataType);
 return false;
});
```

If you want to do constant updates, you can, of course, add timers or some other logic. But I hope you get the idea of how to proceed to such cases;

Answer (score 0):

To answer part of your question, you can use ajax.

```
<html><head></head><body>
<div id="feed"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var refreshtime=10;
function tc()
{
asyncAjax("GET","upload.php",Math.random(),display,{});
setTimeout(tc,refreshtime);
}
function display(xhr,cdat)
{
 if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
 {
   document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
 }
}
function asyncAjax(method,url,qs,callback,callbackData)
{
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    //xmlhttp.cdat=callbackData;
    if(method=="GET")
    {
        url+="?"+qs;
    }
    var cb=callback;
    callback=function()
    {
        var xhr=xmlhttp;
        //xhr.cdat=callbackData;
        var cdat2=callbackData;
        cb(xhr,cdat2);
        return;
    }
    xmlhttp.open(method,url,true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=callback;
    if(method=="POST"){
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xmlhttp.send(qs);
    }
    else
    {
            xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
}
tc();
</script>
</body></html>
```